# Alternative proof for the integral of $1/x$ being equal to $\ln (x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, logarithms

This question relates to an attempt I made to answer the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374894/how-can-i-prove-the-integral-int-1x-frac1t-dt-is-ln-x-with/1392088?noredirect=1#comment2834018_1392088).

I wonder if the approach below counts as an alternative way to show that $$\int_1^{1+x}\frac1t\ \mathsf dt = \ln(1+x).$$ I don't think this constitutes a proof but shows that adding infinitesimally small rectangles following $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$  equals $\ln(1+x)$. Apparently my approach is not correct since it got downvoted. I am still curious as to what is the link between the derivations below and $\ln(1+x)$, since as you may see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27WjT.jpg), both functions are equivalent as $n$ goes to infnity.

The result I obtain is a an infinite sum of infinitesimally small rectangles that mimics perfectly $\ln(1+x)$ for values where $x>-1$. The approach is as follows (copying from my attempt to answer the question on the link posted above):

Start by taking the area of a rectangle that has length $x$ and height $f(x)$. The area is $f(x)\cdot x$. This is too large and a bad approximation. So break the interval from $1$ to $1+x$ by two intervals of length $\dfrac{x}{2}$. Then the area would be, starting from the left:

$$f(1)\cdot \dfrac{x}{2} + f\left(1+\dfrac{x}{2}\right). \dfrac{x}{2} = \dfrac{x}{2} + \frac{2}{1+x}.\frac{x}{2} = x\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2+x}\right) $$

Then, in a third iteration, breaking $x$ into three intervals and calculating the area of the three rectangles, we would get:

\begin{align}
& f(1)\cdot \dfrac{x}{3} + f\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)\cdot \dfrac{x}{3} + f\left(1+2\frac{x}{3}\right)\cdot \dfrac{x}{3}\\ = {} &\dfrac{x}{3} + \frac{3}{1+x}\cdot\frac{x}{3} + \frac{3}{1+2x}\cdot\frac{x}{3}\\ = {} &x\left(\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{3+x} + \dfrac{1}{3+2x}\right)
\end{align}

A pattern starts to emerge. As we break the $x$ interval into smaller and smaller parts and sum the area of the smaller rectangles we approximate better the area under $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. This would give a formula as follows:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x}{n+xk}\right)$$

where $k$ represents the begining points of the bases of the rectangles and $n$ represents by how many chunks we break up $x$. By taking the limit of $n$ going to infinity I get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x}{n+xk}\right)$$

you may notice that this expression seems to be equivalent to $\ln(1+x)$ on the link provided above. I don't know how to prove this mathematically, but if you plot both expressions on a graph you will notice that even with a small value of $n$ we approach quite well the $\ln(1+x)$ function. As $n$ increases both functions seem to converge everywhere.

I want to understand how the infinite sum above relates to $\ln(1+x)$ or if I have made a mistake in the derivations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several definitions for the integral (and in most normal cases they are all equivalent). One very popular one is the [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) which can roughly be defined as (the full definition is a bit more complicated than this but for our purposes here this is not needed)

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx \equiv \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i)\Delta x$$

where $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i = a + \frac{(b-a)i}{n}$. If we apply this to the integral $\int_1^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}$ we get

$$\int_1^{x+1} \frac{dt}{t} \equiv \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x}{n + xk}$$

which is the formula you have. Thus what you have written down is basically just the *definition* of the integral $\int_1^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}$ and has nothing to do with the $\log$ function per ce.

In order to prove that $\log(1+x) = \int_1^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}$ you need to start with a definition of $\log(1+x)$ and then continue to show that the integral you started with is equivalent to that definition. There are several such definition one could start with, for example

- $\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ valid for $x\in(-1,1]$.
- The inverse function of the exponential function $e^x$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought about equating the infinite sum that I mentioned above to the Taylor approximation of $\ln(1+x)$ but from there I can't find a way to continue. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Gustavo Expanding $\frac{1}{1+\frac{xk}{n}}$ is a [geometrical series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) might work. There are many details to be filled in but something like this $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\frac{x}{1+\frac{xk}{n}}$ = $\frac{x}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-xk}{n}\right)^i$ = $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k/n)^i\right] (-1)^ix^{i+1}$ looks like it could work.

Comment: This would give you $\int_1^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^i\right] (-1)^ix^{i+1}= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left[\int_0^1t^idt\right](-1)^ix^{i+1} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{i+1}}{i+1}$ where I have used the definition of the integral $\int_0^1t^idt$

Comment: Yes, it works! thank you! Very helpful